# SSIS Create Folder with CurrentDate

Tags: ssis

I am trying to create a folder with current date using file system task . Package completes the execution successfully, but no folder is created.

I have set the following properties for the file system task

```
IsSourcePathVariable = True
Operation = Create Directory
SourceVariable = User::DestinationFolder
DestinationRoot = D:\Destination\
DestinationFolder = @[User::DestinationRoot]  + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART( "yyyy" , getdate() ) +
                   RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART( "mm" , getdate() ), 2) +
                   RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR,4,1252)DATEPART( "dd" , getdate() ), 2)
```

Comment: Has the `DestinationFolder` variable been set to `EvaluateAsExpression=True`? When you write the expression have you clicked evaluate expression to check it?

Comment: It was set to false. I changes it to true and it worked!! Thank for your help.